# How to validate and handle input when email and phone has same textbox

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am looking for a way to deal with following use case.
A user can enter either phone number or email address in order to get password reset token in an ionic app.I cannot change the UI to have two field as BAs won't accept it.Following screenshot shows the MOCK UI:

[image: Screenshot]

Problem: 1. Since there is just one input field how to validate if user entered either phone number or email address?Is there any definitive regex for it?

2. Since there is just one input but two different type of data, how to decide on model?Should I have just one model(field) of type string and use the same for both after UI validation or should I use two different field as model for this scenario?
3. ANother challenge is enabling the submit button when a valid email address is entered or phone number is entered.Phone number can be of international type.

Comment: Regarding 1. You can probably just have two regexes - first see if it's a phone number. If it fails, check for an email. If that fails give the user a warning something like "are you sure this is right?". As for 2. very hard to say. This input doesn't make much sense but what I'd do is save whatever is put there (*anything*, even if it fails validation) under a "contact". You can name the thing better but the idea is that you are contacting the person via this. This *can* actually be non-standard, e.g., "call XYZ, ask for Bob".

Comment: Thanks Vlaz for your insight, I was thinking the same.I will implement it and see how this spans out.

Comment: (after edit) I actually mentioned it in my previous comment but 3. Don't disable the submit button. There are too many valid things you cannot account for. I understand that somebody handed you this design and you have to work with it, so unless you can talk to them for clarification or to change the design, just let everything through

Comment: In fact it was in their design to disable the button unless a valid input is provided.

Comment: Then I'd ask them to define what "valid" is to them. There are simply too many numbers that could be considered valid. Aside from "ask for Bob" (which is a real thing), you could also have a number with an extension, so you call 555-123 and then have to key in 456 which can be written down as 555-123 (ex 456). Then you have all sorts of regional numbers from all around the world. Some may be, say, four digits long (excluding the area code), others might be much longer. I suppose there is a library out there that probably validates them but a regex will be a poor choice.

Comment: ohh yes regex will be just a primary filter on UI . However I have reached out to them again to define a valid data.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
var input = "your angular model input";
    var emailReg = /^([w-.]+@([w-]+.)+[w-]{2,4})?$/;
if(emailReg.test(input))
{
    $emailModel = input;
} else {
  var mobileRegex = /[0-9 -()+]+$/;
  if((input.length > 6) && (intRegex.test(input)))
  {
    $mobileModel = input; 
  }
}
```

Comment: This email regex is terrible. It will disallow some valid emails. At the very least, I see it doesn't allow `+` in the name part. Among other valid characters. It also doesn't handle non-latin characters. That's assuming you mean `\w` instead of `w`. Moreover, apparently `email@domain1@domain2@domain3.com` is a valid input.

Comment: Its just a suggestion, he could construct the regex he wants